# Integration of square of a continuous function is zero in a given finite range , then is the function also zero in that range?

Tags: integration, continuity

Integration of square of a continuous function is zero in a given finite range , then function is also zero in that range.

How to prove it ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and $I$ an open interval of $\mathbb{R}$.

We have $\int_I f(x)^2 dx = 0$.

Suppose $\exists x_0 \in I$ s.t. $f(x_0) \neq 0$.
Since $f$ is continuous : $$\exists \delta>0, \forall x, |x-x_0|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\dfrac {|f(x_0)|} 2.$$

We can deduce this :

$$\exists \delta>0, \forall x, |x-x_0|<\delta \implies f(x)^2>\dfrac {f(x_0)^2} 4$$

Then $$\int_I f(x)^2 dx \geq \int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0+\delta} f(x)^2 dx \geq \int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0+\delta} \dfrac {f(x_0)^2} 4 dx =  f(x_0)^2 \dfrac \delta 2>0.$$

Hence $x_0$ does not exist and $f \equiv 0$ on $I$.